# Loading flash in webview android 2.2 does not work on emulator

Tags: android, flash

I tried to load the flash using webview, it does not work on emulator but when I tried it on my HTC device it worked.

Please suggest.

Comment: Check that whether your HTC device contains adobe flash player or not.

Comment: Yes my HTC device contains flash player.... but flash does not loads on emulator

Comment: Thats the basic answer, you should install flash inside your emulator to deal with flash.

Comment: I have installed flash player inside emulator.... but don't know why this is not working..... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Flash can't run on the Emulator...
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ad607b175e881df5